# Matplotlib specgram throwing "Invalid shape" TypeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to use Matplotlib's spec gram to create spectrum images, and keep getting an error:

```
TypeError: Invalid shape (513, 1024, 10) for image data
```

The code in which I am calling it is:

```
spectrum, freqs, t, im = plt.specgram(np.asarray(Moves[MoveNum][:,0]), 1024, 300, noverlap=900)
```

The data I am sending in is one-dimensional, and plots cleanly in matplotlib.
[image]

Full error code is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[39], line 1
----> 1 spectrum, freqs, t, im = plt.specgram(np.asarray(Moves[MoveNum][:,0]), 1024, 300, noverlap=900)

File ~/.conda/envs/simple/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py:2863, in specgram(x, NFFT, Fs, Fc, detrend, window, noverlap, cmap, xextent, pad_to, sides, scale_by_freq, mode, scale, vmin, vmax, data, **kwargs)
   2857 @_copy_docstring_and_deprecators(Axes.specgram)
   2858 def specgram(
   2859         x, NFFT=None, Fs=None, Fc=None, detrend=None, window=None,
   2860         noverlap=None, cmap=None, xextent=None, pad_to=None,
   2861         sides=None, scale_by_freq=None, mode=None, scale=None,
   2862         vmin=None, vmax=None, *, data=None, **kwargs):
-> 2863     __ret = gca().specgram(
   2864         x, NFFT=NFFT, Fs=Fs, Fc=Fc, detrend=detrend, window=window,
   2865         noverlap=noverlap, cmap=cmap, xextent=xextent, pad_to=pad_to,
   2866         sides=sides, scale_by_freq=scale_by_freq, mode=mode,
   2867         scale=scale, vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax,
   2868         **({"data": data} if data is not None else {}), **kwargs)
   2869     sci(__ret[-1])
   2870     return __ret

File ~/.conda/envs/simple/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py:1442, in _preprocess_data.<locals>.inner(ax, data, *args, **kwargs)
   1439 @functools.wraps(func)
   1440 def inner(ax, *args, data=None, **kwargs):
   1441     if data is None:
-> 1442         return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)
   1444     bound = new_sig.bind(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1445     auto_label = (bound.arguments.get(label_namer)
   1446                   or bound.kwargs.get(label_namer))

File ~/.conda/envs/simple/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py:7792, in Axes.specgram(self, x, NFFT, Fs, Fc, detrend, window, noverlap, cmap, xextent, pad_to, sides, scale_by_freq, mode, scale, vmin, vmax, **kwargs)
   7789 if 'origin' in kwargs:
   7790     raise _api.kwarg_error("specgram", "origin")
-> 7792 im = self.imshow(Z, cmap, extent=extent, vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax,
   7793                  origin='upper', **kwargs)
   7794 self.axis('auto')
   7796 return spec, freqs, t, im

File ~/.conda/envs/simple/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py:1442, in _preprocess_data.<locals>.inner(ax, data, *args, **kwargs)
   1439 @functools.wraps(func)
   1440 def inner(ax, *args, data=None, **kwargs):
   1441     if data is None:
-> 1442         return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)
   1444     bound = new_sig.bind(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1445     auto_label = (bound.arguments.get(label_namer)
   1446                   or bound.kwargs.get(label_namer))

File ~/.conda/envs/simple/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py:5665, in Axes.imshow(self, X, cmap, norm, aspect, interpolation, alpha, vmin, vmax, origin, extent, interpolation_stage, filternorm, filterrad, resample, url, **kwargs)
   5657 self.set_aspect(aspect)
   5658 im = mimage.AxesImage(self, cmap=cmap, norm=norm,
   5659                       interpolation=interpolation, origin=origin,
   5660                       extent=extent, filternorm=filternorm,
   5661                       filterrad=filterrad, resample=resample,
   5662                       interpolation_stage=interpolation_stage,
   5663                       **kwargs)
-> 5665 im.set_data(X)
   5666 im.set_alpha(alpha)
   5667 if im.get_clip_path() is None:
   5668     # image does not already have clipping set, clip to axes patch

File ~/.conda/envs/simple/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py:710, in _ImageBase.set_data(self, A)
    706     self._A = self._A[:, :, 0]
    708 if not (self._A.ndim == 2
    709         or self._A.ndim == 3 and self._A.shape[-1] in [3, 4]):
--> 710     raise TypeError("Invalid shape {} for image data"
    711                     .format(self._A.shape))
    713 if self._A.ndim == 3:
    714     # If the input data has values outside the valid range (after
    715     # normalisation), we issue a warning and then clip X to the bounds
    716     # - otherwise casting wraps extreme values, hiding outliers and
    717     # making reliable interpretation impossible.
    718     high = 255 if np.issubdtype(self._A.dtype, np.integer) else 1

TypeError: Invalid shape (513, 1024, 10) for image data
```

I am comparing different frequency domain annalyses of acceleration data.  I am making wavelet based images of spectrum, and now need to compare to Spectrograms.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: It is a single problem.  I am passing an array of data that graphs properly, but when it goes into plt.specgram I get an error.  I am not sure how to diagnose the error that I provided in full.